# Android GSM location force update

Tags: java, android

My question is the following.
I'd like to develop a very simple android application what can just get the phones current location from the GSM/3G/LTS/etc. network. I know there is many similar question, but for my problem I can't find any answer.

So I wrote this code and it works nice but when I move to another location in my city and I get again my coordinates, they are same like at my previous position. Cold you help me how can I refresh it without calling, SMS, etc.

(PS: I call the _getLocation() method in a Button Click event)

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            _getLocation();


        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


double lat = 0;
double lon = 0;

LocationListener asd = new MyLocationListener();
Location loc;

private void _getLocation() 
{
    try 
    {   
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        //Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);

        LocationManager fasz = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        fasz.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,10,0,this.asd);

    //Location asdasd =  fasz.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);

        Location asdasd=null;
        MyLocationListener kuki = new MyLocationListener();
        kuki.onLocationChanged(asdasd);

    Toast.makeText(this,  "Long: " + String.valueOf(asdasd.getLongitude()) + "    Lat: " + String.valueOf(asdasd.getLatitude()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //lat = location.getLatitude();
        //lon = location.getLongitude();

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        Toast.makeText(this, ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       // lat = -1.0;
       // lon = -1.0;
    }
}


final class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {



@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location locFromGps) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}
```

}

**Other errors:**

- I needed remove the @Override text from the - onLocationChanged
                                            - onProviderDisabled
                                            - onProviderEnabled
                                            - onStatusChanged         methods.
- I get two more error from the requestSingleUpdate method. About these i attached two pictures.

**First error:**
[image: Error_1]

**Second error:**
[image: Second]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getLastKnownLocation()` return the last known location, a.k.a. does not re-fetch the location.

You will have to register to location updates on the start/resume of the activity (`onStart` or `onResume`), using one of the methods `LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(...)` (I recommend that the activity would implement LocationListener), 
save the new location each time the `LocationListener.onLocationChanged(Location)` is called and use the saved location when the button is pressed.

Another option is registering on the button click, then wait for a location update and only then show a toast.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements LocationListener {

double lat = 0;
double lon = 0;

LocationListener asd = new MyLocationListener();
Location loc;
LocationManager locManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            _getLocation();


        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


private void _getLocation() 
{
    try 
    {   
        this.loc = null;
        locManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, this, null);

        // Waiting for the update
        while(loc == null);

        Toast.makeText(this,  "Long: " + loc.getLongitude() + "    Lat: " + loc.getLatitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(this, ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location locFromGps) 
{
    this.loc = locFromGps;
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}
}
```

Comment: I understand your solution but I'm really new in Java (I'm a C# guy) so could you give me some example or edit my code a bit?

Comment: @Gabor Can you please post more of your activity code so I can edit it?

Comment: I modified my code in the question to the whole MainActivity. :)

Comment: Lot of thanks but I get still some error. Cold you check it? I added two pictures to my post.

Comment: Have you noticed that I've added `implements LocationListener` to the activity?

Comment: Also, you will have to change your minimum SDK level to 9 (You will lose only 0.7% of the potential android users: http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html).

Comment: I passed everything what you wrote but I have still an error when I run the app (both emulated and real device).
It says: `java.lang.NullPointerException` I understand the error message, but don't know what pointer need a value.

I get this message when I make to comment the `while` loop, else it fall into endless cycle or just wait hours I don't know.

Comment: Are you outside? Is your location on (on the device's settings)? Do you have location permissions on your manifest? If you have answered 
"false" for any of these, it may have interrupted you to get your location update.
The 'while' loop just waits until you get a location update.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to read the location updates from the network try using the following method instead:

`requestLocationUpdates(String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, LocationListener listener)`

and pass the provider as LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER